# Saving within a foreach loop (R package)?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, parallel-foreach

I am using the foreach package to run a monte carlo simulation in parallel using HPC. I have no issue with foreach returning the results I want, but I am wondering if it is possible to periodically save the workspace. The reason I ask is that I have to specify a walltime (after which the job is terminated) and so I risk 1. setting the walltime too low and losing everything before the foreach loop has finished and saved my output or 2. setting a conservative walltime and wasting my quota. Ideally, I'd like to be able to periodically save my output, in which case I still have data if the job terminates.

For example:

```
results <- foreach (ii = 1:100, .combine = rbind) %dopar% {
 res1 <- ii^2
 res2 <- matrix(sample(1:9,9,replace = F),nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
 if (ii %% 10 == 0){
   save.image("temp_save.RData")
 }
 results <- list(res1,res2)
}
save.image("final_save.RData")

> load("~/final_save.RData")
> results
           [,1]  [,2]     
result.1   1     Integer,9
result.2   4     Integer,9
result.3   9     Integer,9
result.4   16    Integer,9
...
```

but 'temp_save' is empty, presumably because 'results' is only generated once the foreach loop has finished. Is there any way to access and save these data before the foreach loop has completed? Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can just dump res1 and res2 to file(s), would that be enough?

Comment: What backend are you using? doParallel?

Comment: @Steve I'm using doMC as the backend.

Comment: @Laurik If possible, I'd prefer to save rather than write but thanks for the suggestion - that is definitely an option if I can't use save.

Comment: @yidryi Yes, but you can also save() specific variables instead of the whole image. Worth a try maybe?

Comment: @LauriK Yes that does work. Before I responded, I tried writing both variables to the same .txt file but failed to turn off row.names or col.names, which made a bit of a mess. Writing the number and matrix to separate files without row/col names works nicely - thanks! (I'd still be interested in knowing whether there is way to use save though.)

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem to this one, and solved it using a `save()` method as mentioned in the comments. Specifically, I like intermittently "saving" my progress when working with large datasets so I don't waste computing resources if something goes wrong (e.g. run out of walltime). I have personally found that `save.image()` can be quite unreliable when used in complex code, and especially in an HPC environment. My code is too long to replicate here, but this was the general (untested) method:

```
# Set up the parallel backend
library(doParallel)
library(foreach)
cl <- parallel::makeCluster(4)
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl)

# Set up a scratch directory for your intermediate files
intermediate_directory <- 'INTER_DIR'
if (!dir.exists(intermediate_directory) {
    dir.create(intermediate_directory)
}

# Run your parallel loop
foreach(i = 1:100, .export = ls(environment())) %dopar% {

    # Create a unique filename for each interation of the parallel loop
    each_filename <- paste0('RESULT_', as.character(i), '.rda') 
    each_filepath <- file.path(intermediate_directory, each_filename)

    # If the file exists, skip to the next iteration
    if (file.exists(each_filepath)) {
        next
    }

    # Otherwise, run your code
    each_result <- jitter(i, factor = 10)

    # Save the result individually
    save(each_result, file = each_filepath)

    # OR, save the contents of an environment:
    save(list = ls(environment()), file = each_filepath)

}
```

The results can be re-loaded into a list form after the loop has finished, which is what `foreach` should return anyway. Something like:

```
fls <- list.files(intermediate_directory, pattern = '.rda')
result_list <- lapply(fls, function(x) get(eval(load(x)))
```